# get assoc array elements by array of keys

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array1 = ['key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=>'val2', 'key3'=>'val3']
$array2 = ['key1','key3']
```

I want to get all elements from array1 that has keys in array2.
So the result should be:

```
$result = ['key1'=>'val1', 'key3'=>'val3']
```

I tried array_intersect_key($array1, $array2) but that doesn't work. What is the fastest way to get the above result?

Edit: Forgot to mention that array2 maybe a associative array or single dimension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make key1 and key2 the keys in the second array before you can use array_intersect_key(): use [array_flip()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to do that

```
$result = array_intersect_key($array1,array_flip($array2));
```

**EDIT**

It doesn't matter if $array2 is associative or not:

```
$array1 = array('key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=>'val2', 'key3'=>'val3');
$array2 = array('first'=>'key1','second'=>'key3');

$filteredData = array_intersect_key($array1,array_flip($array2));
var_dump($filteredData);
```

still gives

```
array
  'key1' => string 'val1' (length=4)
  'key3' => string 'val3' (length=4)
```

Comment: See edit, it does not work when array2 is a associative array.

Comment: Show what your $array2 actually is: array_flip() shouldn't care whether it's used on an associative array or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_intersect($a1, $a2){
    $func = function(&$v, $k) {
        $v = (is_string($k)) ? $k : $v;
    };
    array_walk($a2, $func);
    $a2 = array_fill_keys(array_values($a2),1);
    $ret = array();
    if ($a1){
        foreach($a1 as $k => $v){
            if (array_key_exists($k, $a2)){
                $ret[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Kind of ugly by I think it's what the asker wants?  Likely a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Not a purely elegant one-liner, but it'll work:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array2 as $key) {
    $result[$key] = $array1[$key];
}
```

---

In response to edit, just use `values($array2)`.